# "nenhum sintoma" ou "nenhuns sintomas" As duas formas estão corretas?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, número-gramatical, pronomes-indefinidos

Durante uma entrevista à televisão, o técnico do Flamengo Jorge Jesus, com suspeita de ter contraído o novo Coronavírus declarou: "sinto-me muito bem, não tenho **nenhuns sintomas**.  Imediatamente aquilo soou  estranho aos meus ouvidos. Nunca havia percebido alguém usar esse pronome no plural.  É gramatical?  É um regionalismo Lusitano?   Ou até mesmo no Brasil há quem fale dessa forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que a sintax mais correcta -em termos de elegância- é a forma no singular. Mas tal preciosismo é fruto de ponderação.

Se o falante tentar espontaneamente flexionar em número para o plural o resultado está à vista. Isto porque sintomas no plural é comum, e.g. "sem sintomas", "com sintomas", "os sintomas"; talvez mais do que sintoma no singular, "o sintoma"...

Já ouvi ser dito das duas maneiras, no falar leigo e espontâneo do quotidiano talvez a sintax no plural até seja mais comum. Mas decerto num ambiente clínico predomina a sintax no singular.

Quanto ao "Jóta Jóta", tem sido uma delícia (e motivo de orgulho) acompanhar a sua gestão do Flamengo. Por causa dele temos excertos semanais do campeonato brasileiro nos noticiários. Também é conhecido como "catedrático da bola" e pelos seus frequentes "pontapés na gramática". Isto não admira pois semanalmente enfrenta dezenas de jornalistas em conferência de imprensa. Em termos de linguística acho que tomou uma opção correcta, chegou ao Brasil e continuou a falar com pronúnica Europeia, igual a si mesmo.

Comment: Concordo.  O Jorge Jesus é motivo de orgulho para todos os portugueses, e também para nós pois **no momento ele é nosso**.

Comment: Ó chef, a palavr sintax nã exist.S for pra ser precsista, sugiro ants _súntaksis_.

Comment: @ANeves estiveste nos copos, é nítido! (Tive saudades tuas pá, este site sem a tua presença não é a mesma coisa...) Tens razão, falta o eeeeee no final. Mas não me trates por chef camarad, vamos filiar-nos no partido, dar o corpo ao manifesto, fazer a revolução!!

Comment: Estou proibido liminarmente de me dar à confraternização, são os sinais do tempo... mesmo vir aqui, só posso se e quando não cá estiver ninguém! :(